# Elixir - informing other applications about events

Tags: elixir

Let's assume that I have a system (elixir application) that downloads data from the internet, then it will unpack the data (e.g. gzip), parse it (e.g. to get some metadata) and finally will put that data into some local database. After that, the system could be used by other applications (e.g. they can query the data from the system). As we can see, from start till the data is ready to be queried there is some undefined amount of time needed.

Question: what would be the best way in Elixir (pattern/behavior/?) to inform other modules (in a separate application), that the data is now ready in the described system?

Comment: Sending a message, as _literally always_ in OTP. I cannot think of how behaviour might help here.

Comment: Sure on the bottom there will be a message send, but how to "connect" clients with the system? The "other modules" are in separate application.

Comment: @YatenderSingh please don’t suggest abusing `telemetry`, it’s absolutely not a way to go here.

Comment: @Sławek ① make this application accepting callbacks (e. g. through `config.exs` or like,) and call these callbacks after initialization is done _or_ ② use https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html

Comment: Its unclear what kind of clients you have, are they all OTP apps? Or just some sort of HTTP services? If OTP you could connect them and use something like Broadway, if http, then just call them via a webhook, and let them consume the data via an http interface

Comment: The system and the clients are OTP only. I would like to use something that is well know in the community and will not cause "surprise effect".

Answer (score 0):

What ever your apps are doing and you want them to pass event messages that some task is completed you have to ask your self what type of messaging you need?

- Delivery without any guarantees (means your event consumer app don't care if it don't get message for what ever the reason is)
- Delivery with guaranties

  - At least once delivery (means that event consumer app will for sure get message, but sometimes it may get it twice)
  - At most once delivery (means that event consumer app will get each message exactly once!)

So, if you have to solve first case, then pick:

- Erlang built in `pg2`
- Spawn cluster global OTP process that should act as pub/sub mediator (accepts subscribers and then send to them messages when they are emitted)

If you need messaging delivery guaranties to meet, then you need some "backend" that can persist messages until each known consumer acknowledge it read/process it. One way is to write your own "backend" for this, e.g. using `mnesia` or some SQL/NOSQL database, and then on some interval query that backend to see if any event is written. The other way is to use already battle proven bakends, such as RabbitMQ, Kafka... if you need more robust solution.

Please note, that distributed transaction is hard to implement when it comes to messaging. Your task writes to database some data, there may be cases where messaging baccend will be down when write to database is complete, so task processor may not be able to send message to other apps (this also applies to pg2 and global erlang process, no one guarantee that they are up all the time) so you need to think how to recover from such failures. Some small percentage of message may be lost on such infrastructure failures.

One question. Would it be ok if your consumer apps pull from database time to time for new entries? say, task has unique incremental numeric id, then you can use it as read "position" in consumer apps, just write down last written position. Each app should maintain its position during next read interval.

#### --- EDIT ---

One more thing that may be helpful while thinking how to solve this. If you haven't had chance to read about CQRS and "Event Sourcing", please just briefly google it read about it and see what the concept is. To give you brief into about it is that source of the truth is Event Stream, while any other data storages are just event projections to specific moment of time from event stream (some frameworks or people call it event journal) What is interesting about this "Aritechtual Approach" is that you don't need distributed transactions. While Event Stream has purpose to store changes (inserts and updates) during entity lifetime, some backends that are built for this purpose also can help with pushing events to subscribers. I mentioned already [Kafaka](https://kafka.apache.org/), it is often used, but there is also dead simple [EventStore](https://www.eventstore.com/).

I'm not saying that you should build CQRS app, just try to find out how pipeline is organized in such architecture, I'm sure it will help you build reliable pipeline for your case.